# Selenium Python Hangs at click()

Tags: python, selenium

Hello everyone i'm trying to make a bot that uploads a file and reads the percentage of the upload bar. I already have the code to read the percentage, but when i actually click on the upload button it hangs until it is fully uploaded.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("Upload").click()
while 1:
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("Percentage").text
```

I have also tried using threads (This is my first time using threads) and it seems to work the same as just calling the function.

```
def get_percent():
    while 1:
        testy = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("Percentage").text
    print testy
def start_upload():
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("Upload").click()

w = threading.Thread(name='get_percent', target=get_percent())
e = threading.Thread(name='start_upload', target=start_upload())
e.start() #It will hang on upload
w.start()
#if i do it like this instead it will hang in my get_percent function
#w.start() 
#e.start()
```

How do i get around this? Please help

Comment: Is it a public site and you can share a link to it? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium, click on element, hangs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486192/selenium-click-on-element-hangs)

Comment: What the problem is when i click the element, selenium waits until the page is "fully loaded", i need a way to somehow break the e.start() after it clicks or to be able to run e.start() and w.start() at the same time.